# Salesforce - SharePoint File Upload 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, salesforce, apex, apex-code

I am trying to upload file from Apex to Sharepoint but getting error as '400 Bad Request'.But work from JS CODE. Following is my code snippet :

1. Apex Code

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest httpRequestToSend = new HttpRequest();  
httpRequestToSend.setEndpoint('https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(\''+'/sites/siteName/Shared Documents'+'\')/Files/Add(url=\''+'document3.txt'+'\', overwrite=true)');
httpRequestToSend.setMethod('POST');
httpRequestToSend.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
httpRequestToSend.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json; odata=verbose');

httpRequestToSend.setBodyAsBlob(Blob.ValueOf('test Message'));
System.debug('***** httpRequestToSend-->' + httpRequestToSend);
Http http1 = new Http();   
HttpResponse httpResponse1 = http1.send(httpRequestToSend);  
System.debug('***** httpResponse-->' + httpResponse1.toString());
    System.debug(httpResponse1.getBody());
```

2. JS CODE

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token);
        myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");

        var requestOptions = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: myHeaders,
          body: fileBuffer,
        };

        fetch('https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(\'/sites/siteName/Shared Documents\')/Files/Add(url=\'test.txt\', overwrite=true)', requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(result => console.log(result))
          .catch(error => alert('error', error));
      }
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

I was beating my head on this for some time today, and was finally able to get past the "400 Bad Request" error by escaping the space characters in my relative url path (I expect the filename may need the same workaround).

**Each space character (" ") must be replaced with the ASCII reference "%20"**

so in your example, the endpoint url:

```
'https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(\'/sites/siteName/Shared Documents\')/Files/Add(url=\'test.txt\', overwrite=true)'
```

should be changed to:

```
'https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(\'/sites/siteName/Shared%20Documents\')/Files/Add(url=\'test.txt\', overwrite=true)'
```

At least in my case, this corrected the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation **salesforce can't communicate to FTP** directly that means can't Read/Write file at FTP Server.

I also faced this issue and this is how I resolved it:-

Step1: Create & host an External API on in any language(C#, Python) that takes two parameters one as **fileName** and the other one as **fileData** and uploads that file.

Step2: At Salesforce end, consume that API using **HttpRequest** and pass your file as **filedata** and **fileName**.

```
public void uploadFileToFTP_Service(string fileName,string fileData)
{
    string value='{"fileName":"'+fileName+'","fileData": "'+fileData+'"}';
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('http://yourhostedApIPath:9001/data');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setTimeout(120000);        
    req.setHeader('content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
    req.setBody(value);        
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    system.debug('Status code: ' + res.getStatusCode());
}
```